# PowerShell parsing Win-Event XML

Tags: powershell, events, event-log, get-winevent

I've been battling this for a few hours (don't laugh).  What I need is REALLY simple, but I just can't get it.  I avoid Powershell, but I would really like to add it to my portfolio.  Every time I try it, it pisses me off.  Anyway...

The Event data is as follows:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          21/10/2020 14:17:13
Event ID:      4725
Task Category: User Account Management
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      V-XXXXX1.opXXl.local
Description:
A user account was disabled.

Subject:
    Security ID:        OPXXL\w126389
    Account Name:       w126389
    Account Domain:     OPXXL
    Logon ID:       0x43846C4

Target Account:
    Security ID:        OPXXL\nmctest
    Account Name:       nmctest
    Account Domain:     OPXXL
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4725</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>13824</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-21T13:17:13.084423200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>118968190</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="640" ThreadID="1280" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>V-NXXXXX1.oXXl.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">nmctest</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">OXXL</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-3289407757-3693523607-1375118011-18123</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-21-3289407757-3693523607-1375118011-1134</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">w126389</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">OXXXL</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x43846c4</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>



    $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Security";id=4725}
$event = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()
$eventdate = $event | Select-Object -Expand TimeCreated |ForEach-Object {
    $date = [DateTime]$_
    $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffff")
}
$eventdate + "," + $event.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='TargetUserName']")."#text" + ",Account was disabled," + $event.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='SubjectUserName']")."#text"
```

The output is as follows:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\w126389\Documents\event logs.ps1
Select-Object : Property "TimeCreated" cannot be found.
At C:\Users\w126389\Documents\event logs.ps1:3 char:23
+ $eventdate = $event | Select-Object -Expand TimeCreated |ForEach-Obje ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (#document:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
 
,nmctest,Account was disabled,w126389
```

What I'm expecting the output to be is:

```
2020-10-21 13:17:13,nmctest,Account was disabled,w126389
```

You can see I'm getting the other fields I need, everything apart from the date!

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: "You can see I'm getting the other fields I need" - no, we can't see your screen. Please post a sample of the output you're getting, as well as the output you're _expecting_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeCreated` is a property of the original `EventLogRecord` object returned by `Get-WinEvent`:

```
$eventdate = $events[0].TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffff")
```

Comment: Thanks, I don’t really get why the data wasn’t contained in $event though

Comment: @Darren because you've already called `.ToXml()` on the event log record by the time you assign to `$event` - so `$event` is _not_ an event log record, it's an xml document. If you want to extract the value from the XML, you'll have to do it the same way you'd extract the remaining node values: `$event.SelectSingleNode("//TimeCreated").'#text'`

Comment: OK, thank you for that.

I now have working code but it only works on the first event in the collection.  Can you suggest a suitable loop I can use?